# slideToggle jQuery closed on load

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using jQuery `.slideToggle` to create an expanding area when a link is clicked. At present the following code creates a page where the content is showing onload.

How do I specify that the info text should be hidden on page load and only appear when the link is clicked?

```
<script>
    $(".moreInfo").click(function () {
        $(".moreInfoText").slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>


<span class="moreInfo">Read more</span></p>
<p class="moreInfoText">More info text goes here</p>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hide the `p` element directly by adding the `style="display: none;"` attribute:

```
<span class="moreInfo">Read more</span></p>
<p class="moreInfoText" style="display: none;">More info text goes here</p>
```

If you try to do it with javascript, you will get a [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)